# Any better alternatives to "open doors to a new world/findings/horizons/etc. for sb"?

Tags: word-usage

> Results of experimental models show great dependency on site conditions and experiment method. Under these conditions, statistical and AI-based methods (artificial neural networks and fuzzy systems) using available data have opened  door to a new world for researchers.

I suspect "to open door to new horizons/world/etc. for sb" (in figurative sense) is not used this way in English. Is there a better alternative to this usage?

Comment: With the words of the question, these studies may "open new horizons". Also "open up new prospects". Example: *Since then, many research projects have been carried out using in vitro systems, and new prospects have been opened up by utilizing the amazing research material provided by monoxenic plates*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, ending in fluffy statements weakens the writing.

> Results of experimental models show great dependency on site conditions and experiment method. Under these conditions, statistical and AI-based methods (artificial neural networks and fuzzy systems) using available data have opened door to a new world for researchers.

The first sentence is hard to parse.  Consider something like:

> Results of experimental models are strongly dependent on site conditions and experiment methods.

The second sentence also wanders a bit with parenthetical statements, which weakens the impact.

> In such cases, statistical methods, and the AI-based methods of artificial neural networks and fuzzy systems, based on available data, have opened a new world for researchers.

This is still a bit awkward. If my stats and AI aren't too rusty, you can say:

> In such cases, statistical methods, neural networks and fuzzy systems can be applied to available data sets, opening the door to a new world for researchers.

Comment: Is there a difference between "door" and "the door" in this usage? As far as I know, "the" is for known names, right?

Comment: "opened door" isn't grammatical, it would be "opened doors to new worlds" or "open the/a door to a new world", where "a" implies there are many doors, and you'd be obliged to describe the world a bit more (what other doors are there too it?)

Answer (score 1):

To "open the doors to" something is a perfectly acceptable figurative usage in English, so you could say the results have "opened [the] doors to a new world for researchers." and I don't think anyone would complain.

That said, in this kind of context I think perhaps **opened the way to** or even just **opened up** a new world for researchers might be a more natural-sounding way of conveying the same point.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest, "paves the way."